# How to make a copy of a 2D array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, object, copy, variable-assignment

`X` is a 2D array. I want to have a new variable `Y` that which has the same value as the array `X`. Moreover, **any further manipulations with Y should not influence the value of the X.**

It seems to me so natural to use `y = x`. But it does not work with arrays. If I do it this way and then changes y, the x will be changed too. I found out that the problem can be solved like that: `y = x[:]`

But it does not work with 2D array. For example:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4]]
y = x[:]
y[0][0]= 1000
print x
```

returns `[ [1000, 2], [3, 4] ]`. It also does not help if I replace `y=x[:]` by `y = x[:][:]`.

Does anybody know what is a proper and simple way to do it?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try this:

```
from copy import copy, deepcopy
y = deepcopy(x)
```

I'm not sure, maybe [`copy()`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) is sufficient.

Comment: for 2D array of floats copy do not work, but deepcopy does work, thanks!

Comment: copy() is not sufficient, it is a shallow copy so the result will be a copy of references to the original row lists.

Answer (score 135):

Using deepcopy() or copy() is a good solution.
For a simple 2D-array case

```
y = [row[:] for row in x]
```

Comment: +1 for the list comprehension version. It works fine for a 2d array and is way faster that `deepcopy(x)`.

Answer (score 14):

For 2D arrays it's possible use **map** function:

```
old_array = [[2, 3], [4, 5]]
# python2.*
new_array = map(list, old_array)
# python3.*
new_array = list(map(list, old_array))
```

Comment: I think you need to "cast" that, like new_array = list(map(list, old_array))

Comment: distance = list(map(lambda i: list(map(lambda j: j, i)), graph)). I've also seen this....

Answer (score 1):

In your case(since you use list of lists) you have to use [deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html?highlight=deepcopy#copy.deepcopy), because *'The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.'*

Note that sample below is simply intended to show you an example(don't beat me to much) how deepcopy could be implemented for 1d and 2d arrays:

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]

deepcopy1d2d = lambda lVals: [x if not isinstance(x, list) else x[:] for x in lVals]

dst = deepcopy1d2d(arr)

dst[1][1]=150
print dst
print arr
```

Comment: "you have to use deepcopy" Not really. There's always a more complicated, but (maybe) faster way. See Ryan Ye's answer. Yours is fine, but this statement is not perfect.

Comment: @palsch as i can see there is no difference between our answers. Mine deepcopy1d2d doing the same and even more))))

Answer (score 0):

I think [np.tile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) also might be useful

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
>>> np.tile(a, 2)
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
>>> np.tile(a, (2, 2))
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
>>> np.tile(a, (2, 1, 2))
array([[[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
       [[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]])
```