# Modifying a list within a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm attempting to modifying the temp list and store the temp list in the possible list but I need to have list1 unchanged. When I ran this through Python, my temp list has not changed so I'm wondering where this has gone wrong.

```
list1 = [['1', '1', '1'],
     ['0', '0', '0'],
     ['2', '2', '2']]

temp = list1
possible = []

for i in range(len(temp)-1):
    if(temp[i][0] == 1):
            if(temp[i+1][0] == 0):
                    temp[i+1][0] == 1

possible = possible + temp
temp = list1

print(possible)
```

Comment: `temp = list1` is not a copy. You are not creating a temporary list at all. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Use `=`, not `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For copying the array of `list1` to `temp` since, `list1` is 2D array, as suggested by others we can use `deepcopy`. Refer to [this link here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532908/5916727). Alternatively, it can be done using list comprehension as well as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6533065/5916727).

The array has `string` as element, so the conditional statements `if(temp[i][0] == 1)` and `if(temp[i+1][0] == 0)` can be replaced by `if(temp[i][0] == '1')` and `if(temp[i+1][0] == '0')`. And as mentioned above in the comments `temp[i+1][0] == 1` has to be replaced by `temp[i+1][0] = 1`. You can try following:

```
from copy import deepcopy

list1 = [['1', '1', '1'],
         ['0', '0', '0'],
         ['2', '2', '2']]

# copying element from list1
temp = deepcopy(list1)
possible = []
for i in range(len(temp)-1):
    if(temp[i][0] == '1'):
        if(temp[i+1][0] == '0'):
            temp[i+1][0] = '1'


possible = possible + temp

print('Contents of possible: ', possible)
print('Contents of list1: ', list1)
print('Contents of temp: ', temp)
```