# Can't shuffle rows of list of lists by copying (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

I want to shuffle/permute the rows of a list of lists (2D array) `target` in Python.

I create the list `train` and then shuffle it by `np.random.shuffle()`, and use it to permute indices of rows of `target` in the same order.

I know I can't just write new_list = old_list to copy one list to other , so (I think) I used a proper way to copy `target` to `cop` by `cop = [row[:] for row in target]` mentioned [here on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532881/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-python)

But even after running the code below I can't figure out why `cop` changes value during the loop. As a result, `target` isn't what I expect.

Code I am attempting:

```
import numpy as np

train = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

print("train: ", train)
target = np.hstack([np.arange(5).reshape(5,1), np.arange(100, 105).reshape(5,1), 
np.arange(200, 205).reshape(5,1)])

print(target)

np.random.shuffle(train)
print("Shuffled train: ", train)
cop = [row[:] for row in target]

for i in range(len(train)):
    print(train[i], '-----', cop[train[i]], '-------', cop)
    target[i] = list(cop[train[i]])

print("Target: ", target)

print("Cop: ", cop)
```

Sample output:

```
train: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[[  0 100 200]
 [  1 101 201]
 [  2 102 202]
 [  3 103 203]
 [  4 104 204]]
Shuffled train: [4, 3, 2, 0, 1]
4 ----- [  4 104 204] ------- [array([  0, 100, 200]), array([  1, 101, 
201]), array([  2, 102, 202]), array([  3, 103, 203]), array([  4, 104, 
204])]
3 ----- [  3 103 203] ------- [array([  4, 104, 204]), array([  1, 101, 
201]), array([  2, 102, 202]), array([  3, 103, 203]), array([  4, 104, 
204])]
2 ----- [  2 102 202] ------- [array([  4, 104, 204]), array([  3, 103, 
203]), array([  2, 102, 202]), array([  3, 103, 203]), array([  4, 104, 
204])]
0 ----- [  4 104 204] ------- [array([  4, 104, 204]), array([  3, 103, 
203]), array([  2, 102, 202]), array([  3, 103, 203]), array([  4, 104, 
204])]
1 ----- [  3 103 203] ------- [array([  4, 104, 204]), array([  3, 103, 
203]), array([  2, 102, 202]), array([  4, 104, 204]), array([  4, 104, 
204])]
Target:  [[  4 104 204]
 [  3 103 203]
 [  2 102 202]
 [  4 104 204]
 [  3 103 203]]
Cop:  [array([  4, 104, 204]), array([  3, 103, 203]), array([  2, 102, 202]), array([  4, 104, 204]), array([  3, 103, 203])]
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: instead of copying the values by hand of a type that is held as reference (in python that is everything except the primitive types like bool, int, float, str), I recommend to use `target = copy.copy(source)`

Comment: @MarcelZoll That worked, but why did slicing operator on every row not work?

Comment: firstly, to achieve your goal here, i recommend the use of `numpy.take()`; to answer your question why your slicing assignments fails: `cop` still referes to the lists in `target`, which is modified during the loop; as said,complex types should always be explicitly copied